# I can't echo session username, am I storing session username and id correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am setting up a login form.

**Expected Result:**

Echo session username on page after successful login.

**Actual Result:**

Login is successful.  Session username does not echo.  Appears as though session username either does not exist or it is not persisting to the next page.

Is there something wrong with the code below?

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
...
session_start();    
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) ==1)
    {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $profileid = $row['userid'];
    $profile = $row['username'];
    //Set session
    $_SESSION['profileid'] = $profileid;
    //Put name in session
    $_SESSION['profile'] = $profile;
    //Close session writing
    session_write_close();

    //Redirect to user's page
    header("location: index.php?msg=userpage");
    exit();
    }
...
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
...
    <?php
    session_start();    
    if($_GET['msg']=="userpage")
    {
    echo $_SESSION['profile'];

    } 
...
```

Edited: 
Put session_start in php tags. 
Changed HTML to INDEX.PHP.
"If" brace closed.
Changed while to if in LOGIN.PHP.
Changed username to userpage

Comment: Why do you have a `while(mysql_num_rows($result) ==1)`? Why not use an `if`?

Comment: Do some debugging. Instead of redirecting, just print_r the $row. I feel like $row['username']; is undefined.

Comment: ah, it appears that you're onto something.  looks like $row['username']; is in fact undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be opening/closing sessions, it's not worth the extra lines of code. I also don't know why you're regenerating the session ID.

But, one thing is your HTML file is badly constructed, and it almost looks like the session_start() isn't inside any PHP tags, so it's not even being treated as code.

Comment: I thought that regenerating the session id was good practice if you someone else is logged in and you wanted to override it with a new user.  Should I use another function?  I corrected the sloppy html.  I  deleted the session_write_close, but this does not seem to make a difference.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: You can just unset all the important $_SESSION stuff to "clear" a person from the session.

Also, are you closing that open-brace in your HTML file?

Comment: Closed the open brace.  After I use unset, how else could I initiate the session ID?

Answer (score 0):

first of all your **HTML** is yet **PHP** as it involves PHP tags only.

Replace `while` with `if` coz you only want to set the $_SESSION variables once.

And for the last part what you are looking for is this

```
<?php
session_start();   //at the beginning of your script
if($_GET['msg']=="username")
{
 echo $_SESSION['profile'];
}
?>
```

Make sure you eliminate all the whitespaces before the opening of your first `<?php` tag on your script as that gives potential header errors.

Comment: Ok.  Changed while to if.  Sorry, I should have been clearer.  The html is my index page.  Will edit now.  But with all the changes, the result is no different.

Comment: your header has a `location` with small `l` and `username` (which looks like a constant)  instead of `$row['username']`. try `header("Location:index.php?msg=$row['username']")`;

Comment: the case of the "l" in location doesn't seem to make a difference.  I see that my code is confusing.  username here is just a title.  will change it to userpage now.

Answer (score 0):

close the if loop in html file

> **EDITED:**

I did this simple code in my page and as per session concept is concerened The code is working fine...make corrections accordingly

**p1.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();    

        //Put name in session
    $_SESSION['profile'] = "Pranav";
    //Close session writing


    //Redirect to user's page
    header("location: p2.php?msg=userpage");
    exit();

?>
```

**p2.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();    
    if($_GET['msg']=="userpage")
    {
    echo $_SESSION['profile'];

    }

?>
```

**FOR NEW SESSION ID
USE THIS**

```
$a = session_id();
```

Comment: my markup here was sloppy, but it was closed in my local file.  sorry.  corrected it here.